# On a canvas App, what is the App Domain field for?

Tags: facebook, canvas

When building an App on facebook (inside a canvas), I'm not sure what I have to write on the App Domain field (from basic info), should I put there my canvas url too (or perhaps some part of it) ?

This is kind of a big problem because a lot of fb plugins keep asking for a domain field.

Answer (score 0):

This field is basically related to website field, if your will put "yoursite.com" in domain field then in website field you have to put the URL which have to be within that domain like "yoursite.com/index.html".

Comment: Okey but it doesn't make sense if I'm building an app on facebook (inside a canvas) ?

Comment: you can leave that field blank also